# How to add a certificate to the Android trust store?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I got a client app designed for Android. Android apps are based around XML and Java, well so is our server side app for Windows. The issue is that since we are working with Android now, we have to deal with the trust store. Is there any way to add a certificate to the trust store dynamically?

Client side connection code:

```
InputStream stream = main.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
KeyStore trustStore;
try {
  trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
  trustStore.load(stream, "password".toCharArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
try{
  clientSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(address, port);
}catch (Exception ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Server side connection code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "keystore_30290.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
SSLServerSocketFactory factory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
try {
    server = ((SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(config.port));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to successfully bind to port "+config.port+".");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: You create your `KeyStore`, then you don't do anything with it. Try wrapping it in a `TrustManagerFactory`, using that to `init()` an `SSLContext`, and get your `SSLSocketFactory` from the `SSLContext`.

Comment: Can you elaborate in an answer how I would do that? I don't know how to work with SSLContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, given your `trustStore`:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                              KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmfactory.init(trustStore, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keymanagers =  kmfactory.getKeyManagers();

TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory
  .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

tmf.init(trustStore);

SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

sslContext.init(keymanagers, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory factory=sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

Minimum API is 16 for this code.

Comment: Wow, you actually did your code around my code. First person I have seen to take that into consideration. I will vote once I figure out if this works.

Comment: Okay, the code works perfectly. But now I am having another issue. The chat is spammed with messages containing nothing, and when I send a message nothing shows up in the chat. (Does show up on the server side though). I will edit my question quickly to show you how I am reading on the client side.

Comment: Never mind, fixed it by setting a custom length of 512 bytes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Scottie9811: Glad you figured it out. I don't work with low-level sockets much. The code that I showed you was from some code that turns around and uses the `SSLContext` for configuring HTTP clients to use that keystore.

Comment: Just one question, I noticed that TLSv1 context was kinda slow. It also ended up causing issues on how slow it was, as if you send a packet too quick after the first one the first one doesn't get sent. Is there any faster version for android users?

Comment: @SkorrloreGaming-Productions: That depends on your Android version. See [the `SSLContext` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) for a list of candidates. That being said, you also need one that will be compatible with your server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and I didn't set a context for the server side. But I am guessing it auto selected SSLv3 so I am gonna give that a try.

Comment: @SkorrloreGaming-Productions: I hope your server did not select SSLv3. That has [security issues](http://disablessl3.com/).

Comment: Well yeah SSLv3 didn't change much speed wise, but I did notice something with nano timers. And it seems that the speed issue is caused by the app and not the protocol. The message is taking a while to be send through the 'OutputStream'

Comment: I need to install API level 16 for TLSv1.2, I just finished updating the server side code to support specific SSL context, I already see a speed increase by a mile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116319/discussion-between-skorrloregaming-productions-and-commonsware).

Comment: Well I give up, reverting server side code because yeah seems that I get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common no matter what I do with SSLContext on the server side.